# Toggle with checkbox in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app I have an initial state like this:

```
state= {
  graphBackgroundColor: '#fff',
  graphLabelColor: '#000',
}
```

I have a checkbox that calls this function:

```
toggleCOlor = event => {
 console.log('toggling color');
  this.setState({
    graphBackgroundColor: '#000',
    graphLabelColor: '#fff',
    renderCalories: event.target.value === 10
  });
}
```

This works functionally, but no matter whether the ckeckbox is checked or not the colors will now stay what they were set to in that function. How can I make this to toggle so that if the checkbox is checked then graphBackgroundColor is #000 and if it's unchecked it's #fff?

Comment: You have to initialize the state with  graphBackgroundColor: '#fff',

Comment: what do you mean exactly @Owner? I do have the initial state set as that when the module loads

Comment: I think you need to check the check box status. If checked then #fff may be or #000 if not checked

Comment: @Tom N. Is there any value assigned to the Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
toggleCOlor = event => {
 console.log('toggling color');
  this.setState({
    graphBackgroundColor: this.state.graphBackgroundColor === '#000' ? '#fff' : '#000',
    graphLabelColor: this.state.graphLabelColor === '#fff' ? '#000' : '#fff',
    renderCalories: event.target.value === 10
  });
}
```

If you want, you can write a function which passes in the current colour and return the toggled colour instead of the one lined ternary operator.

```
returnAlternateColor = (color) => {
    if(color === "#fff") return '#000;
    if(color === '#000') return '#fff';
}
```

and then call this function passing `this.state.graphLabelColor` instead of the ternary operator. This way you can have even more options.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
     this.setState(prevState => ({
      graphBackgroundColor: prevState.graphBackgroundColor === '#000' ? '#fff' : '#000',
      graphLabelColor: prevState.graphLabelColor === '#fff' ? '#000' : '#fff',
       renderCalories: event.target.value === 10
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

create a function onChange to check or unckeck

```
onChange=(e)=>{
 [e.target.name]:e.target.value
}
```

you can create a function for example to change of color:

```
myStyleWithConditional=()=>{
   background:event.target.value === 10? "#000":"#fff"
}
```

and in your return

```
<div style={this.myStyleWithConditional}></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value=10>
```